# refrence to document ID

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
    @IBAction func NextButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    //validate the fileds
    let Error = validateFields()

    if Error != nil {

    // there is somthing wrong with the fields show error message
            showError(Error!)

        }
    else {

    // create cleaned versions of the data
    let Password = PasswordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: 
    .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let Email = EmailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: 
    .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let Firstname = FirstnameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: 
    .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let Lastname = LastnameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: 
    .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let Age = AgeTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: 
    .whitespacesAndNewlines)


    // create the user
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: Email, password: Password) { 
    (results, Err) in

    // check for errors
    if Err != nil {
    // there was an error creating the user

    self.showError("Error creating user")


    }

    else {

    // user was created succesfully store user info
    let db = Firestore.firestore()



    db.collection("users").document(results!.user.uid).setData(["first 
    name":Firstname, "last name":Lastname, "age":Age, 
    "uid":results!.user.uid]) { (Error) in


    if Error != nil {
    // show error message
    self.showError("error saving user data")

    }
    }


    //transition to the home screen
    self.transitionToHome()

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

So basically here I am authenticating the user on firebase. (I made 
the document ID = the user ID) then I am entering the users info 
into the firebase database into a document where its ID is also 
equal to the users ID from when they are authenticated. Now what I 
am trying to do is to create or get a reference to the document ID 
where some of the users info is already stored like name, last name, 
age... so I can later add/merge more info into that same document 
the name, last name and age is stored under. This is how I am trying 
to merge the info together in a diffrent view controller

```
    db.collection("users").document(*******).setData(["middle 
    Name":Middlename, "favourite colour":Favouritecolour], merge: true) 
    { (Error) in

    if Error != nil {
    // show error messgae
    self.showError("error saving user data")
        }
     }
```

Where I put "*******" is where I am supposed to reference the 
document ID so I can merge/add this info into the same document as 
the other users information where the name, last name and age is 
stored.
                                                                                                                                                                                                  The code I showed you and asked about earlier on how to get a 
document ID from, was code I found on stack overflow where they guy 
had a similar problem as mine. He was trying to access something out 
of his document  but I am just trying to create a reference to the 
document ID.
The code form earlier:

```
    func getDocument() {

    //get specific document from current user
    let docRef =  
  Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUs er?.uid ?? "")

    //get data
    docRef.getDocument { (document, Error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
    let dataDescription = document.data()
    print(dataDescription?["uid"]) 
    } else {
    print("Document does not exist") 

            }

        }

    }
```

But I don't know if this code will help me, I just thought it might 
because its also accessing the document, thats why I though it might 
be my answer to getting the document ID.
So basically my question is what do I need to do wether its adding 
to the code I found on this site, or if I have to write my own code, 
so I can get a reference to the Document ID where my name, last name 
and Age is stored, so I can merge more Info into that document

Thank You Very Much!!!

Comment: To get the current user's UID you can use `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` (also see the docs on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)). What isn't working about the code in your last snippet when you run it?

Comment: well i'm trying to create a reference to the document ID and then taking that refrence andk making sure its a string so i can enter it into: db.collection("users").document(*******).setData(["middle 
    Name":Middlename, "favourite colour":Favouritecolour], merge: true) 
    { (Error)                                                                                                                            Thats what i'm trying to do with that code, just not sure how to?

Comment: If there is a user, calling `uid` on them returns a string. What is going wrong when you run this line ` Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUs er?.uid ?? "")`. The only thing I see wrong is the space in `currentUser` and the fact that you're not checking if there is a current user.

Comment: How would I Check for a current user?

Comment: `if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil)`? If you want to listen for the user (so automatically run some code **when** the user is signed in), see the first snippet in the link in my first comment.

Comment: Hey Adar. Did you get a chance to try the last update?

Comment: Hey Frank, yeah I did with that and some tweaking it all worked, Thank you man!!!

Comment: Good to hear  .

Answer (score 0):

To print the document ID do something like this:

```
let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")

// Get data
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data()
        print(dataDescription?["firstname"])
        print(document.documentID)
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

I highly recommend spending some time in the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), as this is covered in there under [getting multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

Comment: hey whats up Frank, can you give me a better answer, you seem like a nice guy and I'm sure a great programmer but this answer is extremely broad. Can you show me what I have to do and the code I need to write in order to make a reference to the document ID as a string and help me understand what differs between document ID and the UID if the document ID is also my UID in my database. I have been struggling with this for quite some time now and have not had much success in firestore documentation

Comment: My answer shows you how to get the document ID: `print(document.documentID)`. I even gave you the source of where I got that code from in the documentation. I didn't (and still don't) understand the other part of your question, so can't answer that. But downvoting an answer from the one person who tries to help you is not a good look. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: To be frank with you, Frank, I am not the guy that downvoted your answer to my question, I do not have enough "reputation" to do that. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ and frank-ly, your answer was not that helpful

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I usually can parse ambiguous questions reasonably well, but am clearly failing here. It might be good if you can edit the question to clarify the the problem as it's so far attracted one upvote, one downvote, and two close votes saying "This question should include more details and clarify the problem" (none of those from me btw). For example: what isn't working about the code you shared? Or when trying to add more code, what did you try that didn't work? With that we can hopefully get to a common understanding of the problem, and from there help you solve it.

Comment: ok perfect!!! Thank you Frank, your a good man!!! let me clarify my question, tell me if it makes sense